# Rotate Part of a model WPF

Tags: wpf, 3d

I'm developing a flight simulator and have come across the problem of animating the individual pieces of the airplane (i.e. propeller, elevator, rudder, etc...). I created a class that stores the parts of the planes, which contains GeometryModel and a ModelVisual3D that is constructed from an STL file. When I apply the rotation to the specific part, nothing happens in the application. Full code can be found at: [https://github.com/espina7/CSProblems/blob/main/MainWindow.xaml.cs\](https://github.com/espina7/CSProblems/blob/main/MainWindow.xaml.cs%5C)

```
public Part RotatePart()
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Rotating Part");
                Part temp;
                temp = this;
                AxisAngleRotation3D axisAngle = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 10);
                RotateTransform3D myRotate = new RotateTransform3D(axisAngle);
                Vector3DAnimation myVectorAnimation = new Vector3DAnimation(new Vector3D(-1, -1, -1), new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
                myVectorAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                myRotate.Rotation.BeginAnimation(AxisAngleRotation3D.AxisProperty, myVectorAnimation);
                Transform3DGroup partGroup = new Transform3DGroup();
                partGroup.Children.Add(this.part.Transform);
                partGroup.Children.Add(myRotate);
                temp.part.Transform = partGroup;

                temp.recalculateNormals();
                return temp;
            }
```